# How to configure Combobox from Gui Builder?

Tags: codenameone

I can not make combobox from gui builder.
I drag and drop a combobox into place from Components Pallete/Core Combonets.

I am setting two values as is shown in the screen shot bellow:
[image]

I am saving the From in the gui builder and then I hit the run on netbeans. On simulator the combobix is shown empty as you can see on the next screenshot:
[image]

am I dong something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the GUI builder. We generally recommend [avoiding combo boxes](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-dont-use-combobox.html) so people don't test this much. Please [file an issue here](http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/). As a workaround just use `setModel` within the constructor and define the elements that go in.